# How to use StartCopyFromBlob between different accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I am using this code to copy blobs from one account to another... but it throws an exception.

```
var srcAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string 1");
var dstAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string 2");

var srcBlobClient = srcAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var dstBlobClient = dstAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

foreach (var srcCloudBlobContainer in srcBlobClient.ListContainers())
{
    var dstCloudBlobContainer = dstBlobClient
        .GetContainerReference(srcCloudBlobContainer.Name);

    dstCloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

    foreach (var srcBlob in srcCloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs())
    {
        if (srcBlob.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
        {
            var srcBlockBlock = (CloudBlockBlob)srcBlob;
            var dstBlockBlock = dstCloudBlobContainer
                .GetBlockBlobReference(srcBlockBlock.Name);

            // throws exception StorageException:
            // The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
            dstBlockBlock.StartCopyFromBlob(srcBlockBlock.Uri);
        }
    }
}
```

Microsoft states that cross account copy is supported, but I cannot get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I may be worth noting for future visitors that `StartCopyFromBlob` is now deprecated and has (I believe) been replaced with `StartCopy`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you check the source blob container's ACL? If it's **`Private`** you may either need to change the ACL to **`Public`** / **`Blob`** or create a SAS URL. You can use the following code if you wish to keep your blob container's ACL as `Private` and make use of SAS URL:

```
var srcAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string 1");
var dstAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string 2");

            var srcBlobClient = srcAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
            var dstBlobClient = dstAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            foreach (var srcCloudBlobContainer in srcBlobClient.ListContainers())
            {
                var dstCloudBlobContainer = dstBlobClient
                    .GetContainerReference(srcCloudBlobContainer.Name);

                dstCloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

                //Assuming the source blob container ACL is "Private", let's create a Shared Access Signature with
                //Start Time = Current Time (UTC) - 15 minutes to account for Clock Skew
                //Expiry Time = Current Time (UTC) + 7 Days - 7 days is the maximum time allowed for copy operation to finish.
                //Permission = Read so that copy service can read the blob from source
                var sas = srcCloudBlobContainer.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
                {
                    SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-15),
                    SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(7),
                    Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                });
                foreach (var srcBlob in srcCloudBlobContainer.ListBlobs())
                {
                    if (srcBlob.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                    {
                        var srcBlockBlock = (CloudBlockBlob)srcBlob;
                        var dstBlockBlock = dstCloudBlobContainer
                            .GetBlockBlobReference(srcBlockBlock.Name);
                        //Create a SAS URI for the blob
                        var srcBlockBlobSasUri = string.Format("{0}{1}", srcBlockBlock.Uri, sas);
                        // throws exception StorageException:
                        // The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
                        dstBlockBlock.StartCopyFromBlob(new Uri(srcBlockBlobSasUri));
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Is it possible to cancel the SAS after the copy operation finishes?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do so, however it will complicate your code a little bit. For this, SAS must be created using an `Access Policy`. What you would need to do is create an access policy on the source container with `Read` permission and define the SAS expiry date just before copying. Since copying blob is an async process you would need to monitor the progress of the copy operation. Once the copy operation is finished, you could delete that access policy. You can read more about access policy here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee393341.aspx.

Comment: Hi, It seems this post is old, but I'm having trouble with copying a blob between storage accounts as well. What is interesting, is that the copy works fine when copying within the same storage account. Regarding the SAS - do I really need to have SAS for the copy operation ?